# Esper 8.2 deploy performance

Tags: performance, esper

I'm prototyping an Esper for an event matching solution in which I create queries dynamically.  Overall I am satisfied with the performance of the matching engine itself.  However, there is a curious problem with the deployment of new queries.  At the start of the day calling DeploymentServer.deploy() takes < 100ms.  As the day goes by and more events are loaded into the engine the deploy() call grows slower and slower reaching 1.5 seconds at the end of the day when the process grows to ~ 40G in virtual memory.  Even if there are no events coming in and no other processing at the end of the day, the deploy() call with be slow.  There is also another large process on the box, but there is plenty of free memory on the system.

I tried deploying / undeploying the same statement during the day and the deploy() time will grow even if there are no other statements in the system.

Cheers,

Robert

Any ideas why this would happen and can it be avoided?

Robert

Comment: Hmm interesting, is this deploying only and never un-deploying? How many deployments? For a JVM a process size of 40G is pretty large and perhaps you could optimize the deployments to share data windows with named windows or such, so that deployments need less memory. But without knowing any details its hard to say. Perhaps post some example queries how each of the deployments look like.

Comment: This happens with a sequence of deploy/undeploy calls during the day -- ie. deployments don't accumulate.  At most there would be up to 5 deployments as they will get undeployed when the client disconnects.  The query is over a single named window which by the end of the day contains ~ 3 million events.  The query could be as simple as "select * from NamedWindow" or a bit more complicated with event filters but no joins.  The complexity of the query does not affect it's deployment time much -- it only seems to be only affected by the size of the process and/or the number of events.

Comment: Would 3 million events add up to 40GB? You can inspect with a profiler to see where the 40GB went. The large memory may cause the slow down.

Comment: The events are 1k each which accounts for at least 30G.  Why would memory cause the slowdown?  Sending events does not seem to be much slower only the deploy.  Is there some kind of index built during deploy for these simple filter queries?

Comment: 3 million events at 1k each accounts for 3 GB and not 40 GB so there is something off. Yes there can be index maintenance depending on what the EPL queries look like. A JVM can generally slow down due to garbage collection and monitoring GC would be good.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 10k per event, which is how much unpacking in c++ takes roughly.  I do monitor the GC and it doesn't typically run during deploy.  So wrt indexing, would event filters scan through all data during deploy to build index?  It can only be used for existing data and not new events since filters are per event.

Comment: Something like "create index" would surely build an index. Any joins and subqueries can also build indexes. 10k per event seems a little much. When there are aggregations on named windows these also need to get computed when a query for a named window deploys.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that depending on the queries there are certain things computed as deployment-time. I.e. when there is a named window or table filled with events and that the queries refer to that named window or table. For example `create index` would build an index. Any joins and subqueries can also build indexes. When there are aggregations on named windows these also need to get computed when a query against a named window deploys. Thus if you already have millions of events the deploy step can take time. If you can provide the specific query I can provide more information.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this.  What is strange is that the queries are pure event filters without joins.  I would not have expected indexing of all events to be happening in this case as it is not useful for the running query; it would only be useful with the initial "replay" snapshot of the query.  But it seems that even these simple event filter queries do scan through all events.  I'm trying to work around this by having two named windows with recent events going into the smaller one and then moving to the large one.  Setting up a query for the small window should be faster.